# Object initializtion

Tags: c++

I've seen the following code snippet: `test()` function output is 6

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int z = 0;
    class A{
public:
    int a = 2;
    A(){
        a = 1; 
        z++;
    }
    A(const A& aa){
        a = 3;
        z += 2;
    }
    A& f(){return *this;}
};

void test(){
    {A a, b(a), c(A().f());}
    cout << z;
}

int main()
{
    test();

    return 0;
}
```

I understand what happens in all lines except object `c` initialization: `c(A().f())`? I'd would be glad, if you explain me this line?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher: What do you mean?  It's a third local variable of type `A`, scoped to the inner block.  There's `A a` (default initialization), `A b(a)` (direct call to copy constructor), and `A c(A().f())` (another direct call to copy constructor, copying a temporary which was value initialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines breaks down like this:

```
A a;     // Calls A::A();  (Default constructor. Has `z++;`, so `z` is now 1)
A b(a);  // Calls A::A(const A&);  (Copy constructor. `z += 2;`, so `z` is now 3)
A c(
  A()    // Calls A::A();  (`z++;`, `z` is now 4)
         // This creates a temporary `A` object
  .f()   // Just returns `*this`, the temporary. No copy made, nothing happens to `z`
);       // Calls A::A(const A&);  (`z += 2;`, `z` is now 6)
```